# Accessing JSON nested via key with no value using Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to return the values of JSON objects which are nested within a complex array of objects. Unfortunately I've not been able to do it easily as the structure of the JSON seems unusual; for example:

```
var cartContents = { 
  "contents":
     {
       "ed2be4abf6cc927dd670b567efd42fc3":
         {
           "id": "1288785070733722605",
           "quantity":2,
           "limit":10,
           "offset":0,
           "order":null,
           "created_at":"2016-07-06 12:18:10",
           "updated_at":"2016-07-06 12:18:34",
           "sku":"006",
           "title":"Fishing Rod",
           "slug":"fishing-rod-lara-fluorescent-print",
           "sale_price":0,
           "status":{
             "value":"Draft",
             "data": {
               "key":"0",
               "value":"Draft"
             }
           },
           "category": 
             {
               "value":"Bottom",
               "data": 
                 {
                   "1228355758422329063":  
                     {
                       "id":"1238352758122309063",
                       "order":null,
                       "created_at":"2016-07-06 11:23:54",
                       "updated_at":"2016-07-06 11:38:23",
                       "parent":
                         {
                           "value":"All Sports",
                           "data":
                             {
                               "id":"2288364532150634121",
                               "order":null,
                               "created_at":"2016-07-06 11:37:25"...
                             }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
   }
```

The following code produces the correct result ("Fishing Rod"):

```
var x = cartContents.contents;
console.log(x.ed2be4abf6cc927dd670b567efd42fc3.title);
```

However the whole point is that the 32 character string ('ed2be4abf6cc927dd670b567efd42fc3') represents one of many products, each with a random 32 bit string and therefore they can't be individually coded into the JS.

I've tried a very great deal of different ways. The latest is the following code (where 'carts' is an array of unique 32 character strings:

```
var x = cartContents.contents;    
$.each(carts, function() {
     console.log(x.this.title);
});
```

The result is "jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined".

Would greatly appreciate help accessing the following keys and their values:

1. "title":"Fishing Rod"
2. "id":"1238352758122309063"
3. "created_at":"2016-07-06 11:37:25"

Also worth mentioning that I can't touch the server, therefore I can't change the data structure at all.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can provide some example data to work on it, it would be very helpful.

Comment: `$.each(x, function() {
     console.log(this.title);
});`

Comment: or `$.each(carts, function() { console.log(x[this].title); });` (but I wonder how you may hardcode the array `cart` when the property-names are random)

Comment: @Dr.Molle - arrrrghhh... thank you. So obvious. Have been coding too long. If you answer formally I will accept it as the right one.

Comment: There's no JSON shown in your question. [There ain't no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @Dr.Molle - I had a nightmare with that - the values which are going into the 'cart' array are being stored as cookies, which I am then reading back and pushing into the array... perhaps not correct to say that they are 'random' - more that they are each unique. Quick question - does your answer above show that you can use $.each to get 'further down' within the JSON, even if you do not provide the data from the 'carts' array?

Comment: @nnnnnn my apologies. How should this data be described?

Comment: JSON is a string format used for data interchange, so you may be receiving the data from the server as JSON, but once you've parsed it (or jQuery has parsed it for you if you used its Ajax methods) you just have an object. It's the resulting object that you are trying to manipulate here to get those particular fields. See the page I linked to for more info.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks that's useful to know.